# Can't see "Chart" field

Tags: 7, entities

I'm having an issue where the 'chart' field from the easycharts module is not visible on the content type when I'm creating. I've installed libraries for easychart and highcharts, and have no idea what the issue could be.

Anyone run into this issue?

[image: chart content type creation page[1]]

Comment: Check status report to make sure no library is missing, check error log.